# How to block WhatsApp traffic in TP Link router?

Tags: router, whatsapp

Can anyone tell me how to block Android WhatsApp traffic in a TP Link router?

Comment: Guys i used " c.whatsapp.net and whatsapp.net" it's working for me....

Comment: Then post that as an answer?

Comment: Also, did you want to block all WhatsApp traffic from all devices or just the one device?

Comment: *"...in a TP Link router"* - TP link produces a variety of routers in various price ranges and with widely different capabilities. It is completely unclear what capabilities your specific model has.

Answer (score 1):

When ever someone builds a public service, their goal is to make it available for everyone. That's why it's way easier to find guidance for allowing traffic than denying it and do the opposite. Facebook has published information for WhatsApp Business API [Network Requirements](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/network-requirements/), but that page has a link to a downloadable IP address/range list for WhatsApp servers. (The link has removed from the citation intentionally as it seems like a changing one.)

> WhatsApp uses a wide range of IP addresses for its servers. You can
>   try to allow all of the IP addresses. However, it is best to just
>   allow all outgoing traffic and connections from the above ports.
>
> List of WhatsApp Server IP Addresses and Ranges (.zip)

From that information we can also deduce that it would be easier to block the ranges on a consumer grade router, as WhatsApp is able to fallback to HTTPS port `443`. The IPv4 ranges on the list are from `/32` or `/26` are are likely to change. If you need to add them to current TP-Link router's *Access Control > Target* one by one you would have lots of work.

Most of the IP addresses are from Facebook's range `31.13.64.0/18`, but that would block all the other Facebook services, too. Furthermore, some of the addresses seems to be random addresses from `softlayer.com` etc. Pretty much a Game Over for that approach. (For *allowing* WhatsApp through a firewall, TCP ports `5222`, `5223`, `5228` and `3478` to `31.13.64.0/18` have been enough.)